# why do change_column in migration not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
change_column :posts, :ID, :string, :null => false
```

I have used this after the add_column but when i leave the value as empty it does not show any error. why and what can i do to capture the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use validation inside your model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :column_name, presence: true
end
```

And it better to do not use :id to store some string. This column name is reserved in Rails.